# Unable to upload images to directory using move_uploaded_file?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i am currently having problem uploading file on my folder, using move_uploaded_file function here is my code :-

```
<?php
//Check whether the user has uploaded a profile pic or not
  //Profile Image upload script
  if (isset($_FILES['profilepic'])) {
   if (((@$_FILES["profilepic"]["type"]=="image/jpeg") || (@$_FILES["profilepic"]["type"]=="image/png") || (@$_FILES["profilepic"]["type"]=="image/gif"))&&(@$_FILES["profilepic"]["size"] < 1048576)) //1 Megabyte
  {
   $chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
   $rand_dir_name = substr(str_shuffle($chars), 0, 15);
   $dir = __DIR__."userdata/profile_pics/$rand_dir_name";
   mkdir($dir);
    move_uploaded_file(@$_FILES["profilepic"]["tmp_name"],"./userdata/profile_pics/$rand_dir_name/".$_FILES["profilepic"]["name"]);
    $profile_pic_name = @$_FILES["profilepic"]["name"];
    $profile_pic_query = mysqli_query($conn,"UPDATE users2 SET profile_pic='$rand_dir_name/$profile_pic_name' WHERE username='$user'");

  }
  else
  {
      $msg5 =  "Invailid File! Your image must be no larger than 1MB and it must be either a .jpg, .jpeg, .png or .gif";
  }
  }

?>
```

And i am uploading file from www.domain.com/editprofile folder and it doesn't seem to move file and upload it to www.domain.com/userdata/randomfolder. I don't know but is file uploading is not happening because of my .htaccess code. here is my .htaccess.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9._-]+)/?$ profile.php?u=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Form set to POST and using a valid enctype? Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.

Comment: *" it doesn't seem to move file and upload it to www.domain.com/userdata/randomfolder"* - If you're trying to use a domain `www.domain.com` rather than a system path to, then that's most likely the reason, or part of it.

Comment: @Fred-ii- i get the following errors, what should i do : 'Warning: mkdir(): No such file or directory in /home/rahulkapoor90/public_html/editprofile/index.php on line 117

Warning: move_uploaded_file(./userdata/profile_pics/eH0xpOnjJdzEqVL/2015-04-07_2223.png): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/rahulkapoor90/public_html/editprofile/index.php on line 118

Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/tmp/phpYDzKxw' to './userdata/profile_pics/eH0xpOnjJdzEqVL/2015-04-07_2223.png' in /home/rahulkapoor90/public_html/editprofile/index.php on line 118'

Comment: Someone provided you with an answer below. An answer doesn't always mean a "solution", so give it a try and see, if you haven't seen it yet.

Answer (score 0):

in below line.....

```
 move_uploaded_file(@$_FILES["profilepic"]["tmp_name"],"./userdata/profile_pics/$rand_dir_name/".$_FILES["profilepic"]["name"]);
$profile_pic_name = @$_FILES["profilepic"]["name"];
```

might u should use...

```
move_uploaded_file(@$_FILES["profilepic"]["tmp_name"],"../userdata/profile_pics/$rand_dir_name/".$_FILES["profilepic"]["name"]);
```

or

```
move_uploaded_file(@$_FILES["profilepic"]["tmp_name"],"/userdata/profile_pics/$rand_dir_name/".$_FILES["profilepic"]["name"]);
```

Comment: Can you explain the differences between the two options you've provided and the reasons why they may/may not work better?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution finally, here :

```
<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);
  if (isset($_FILES['profilepic'])) {
   if (((@$_FILES["profilepic"]["type"]=="image/jpeg") || (@$_FILES["profilepic"]["type"]=="image/png") || (@$_FILES["profilepic"]["type"]=="image/gif"))&&(@$_FILES["profilepic"]["size"] < 1048576)) //1 Megabyte
  {
   $chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
   $rand_dir_name = substr(str_shuffle($chars), 0, 15);
   $dir = "/home/rahulkapoor90/public_html/userdata/profile_pics/$rand_dir_name";
   mkdir($dir);
    move_uploaded_file(@$_FILES["profilepic"]["tmp_name"],"/home/rahulkapoor90/public_html/userdata/profile_pics/$rand_dir_name/".$_FILES["profilepic"]["name"]);
    $profile_pic_name = @$_FILES["profilepic"]["name"];
    $profile_pic_query = mysqli_query($conn,"UPDATE users2 SET profile_pic='$rand_dir_name/$profile_pic_name' WHERE username='$user'");

  }
  else
  {
      echo  "Invailid File! Your image must be no larger than 1MB and it must be either a .jpg, .jpeg, .png or .gif";
  }
  }

?>
```

Comment: I had a feeling it was the way you set your path; that's why I mentioned that in comments.